# Gradle Copy task does not copy files

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, mockito, powermock

I have the following task to copy files from my android projects resources files to a different path that is accessible by a ClassLoader instance in a unit test.

```
task copyResDirectoryToClasses(type: Copy){
    println 'COPYINGCOPYINGCOPYING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
    println "$projectDir/src/test/java/com/textmeinc/topmeup/resources/"
    println "$buildDir/intermediates/classes/test/staging/debug/"

    from "$projectDir/src/test/java/com/textmeinc/topmeup/resources/"
    into  "$buildDir/intermediates/classes/test/staging/debug/"
}

assembleDebug.dependsOn(copyResDirectoryToClasses)
```

I see the task run in my gradle console.

```
Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
COPYINGCOPYINGCOPYING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
/Users/tylerpfaff/Documents/Development/topmeup-android/app/src/test/java/com/textmeinc/topmeup/resources/
/Users/tylerpfaff/Documents/Development/topmeup-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/test/staging/debug/
```

However, no files are transferred. If I manually move them in the terminal, my tests run fine with my mock.json file. Why isn't the copy working?

This is the command I used to copy the file manually.

```
cp /Users/tylerpfaff/Documents/Development/topmeup-android/app/src/test/java/com/textmeinc/topmeup/resources/mock.json /Users/tylerpfaff/Documents/Development/topmeup-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/test/staging/debug/
```

Comment: You copy to `classes/test/staging/debug/` in terminal, but `classes/staging/debug/` in gradle task.

Comment: See my edit, still not working :( @LawrenceChoy

Comment: Can you try specifying filename (mock.json) in the `from` section of the task?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy didn't work :(

Comment: Are you potentially running into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505629/gradle-copy-task-not-copying-files-from-temp-folder-first-time-around ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a bug in the plugin. I just ran into this myself. Getting the task to run as a "dependsOn" fails. But if I open the Gradle tab in Android Studio and run the task manually from there, then files are copied. Same goes for command line `gradlew :subproject:copytask`. I'm going to try to replicate this in an independent project and if I can, i'll submit a bug report for it (and put the link here). In the meantime, manually running that gradle task is my only solution.

Comment: Thanks for your research! This is incredibly annoying.

Comment: do you have a bug report for this?

Comment: @desgraci negative, it's been a while, but from my recollection, I was unable to reproduce that in a standalone project for documentation purposes. I want to say that it did eventually get resolved in a future update, but again a while ago, so I can verify for sure when.

Answer (score 0):

The examples at the top of [this documentation page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) use paths that are relative to `projectDir`

Try replacing your from and into paths with:

```
from 'app/src/test/java/com/textmeinc/topmeup/resources'
into 'build/intermediates/classes/test/staging/debug'
```