# Gradle Task not running second run - inconsistent

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have simple task to explode a WAR file and put it under dist folder.

```
task deploy(type: Copy){
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    def distFolder = file('/home/gradle-migration/dist/MyApp')
    def warFile = file('/home/gradle-migration/build/MyApp.war')

    if( !distFolder.exists() ) {
        distFolder.mkdirs()
    }else{
        println "dist exists"
    }
    println "-----------------------------------------------"
    from zipTree(warFile)
    into distFolder
    println "----------------------------------------------"

}
```

The WAR file exists at the location. Trust me
Exploded war was created. But subsequent run didnt do anything.

```
gradle --daemon --rerun-tasks  deploy
```

**Maven was better**

```
19:47:54.467 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep] Determining if task ':deploy' is up-to-date
19:47:54.468 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep] Task ':deploy' is not up-to-date because:
  Task.upToDateWhen is false.
19:47:54.470 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep] Ensuring directory exists for property destinationDir at /xxxxx/tomcat-webapps/MyApp
19:47:54.470 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':deploy'.
19:47:54.471 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute copy for :deploy' started
19:47:55.220 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute copy for :deploy'
19:47:55.220 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute copy for :deploy' completed
19:47:55.220 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskFingerprinter] Fingerprinting property destinationDir (Output) for task ':deploy'
19:47:55.434 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
19:47:55.435 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Task :deploy'
19:47:55.435 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Task :deploy' completed
19:47:55.435 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor] :deploy (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 1.331 secs.
19:47:55.436 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: released lock on :
19:47:55.436 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.8 completed (1 worker(s) in use)
19:47:55.436 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker: released lock on root.1.8
```

Comment: Ordinary it won't do much, while nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe related https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1062. Though the question is not detailed enough for others to debug. Consider giving the exact sequence of commands and more log (like the debug statements you added)

Comment: Also maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505629

Comment: Please note that your `println` statements run during configuration phase, so they cannot be used to debug the actual task.